# Помогите решить вопрос передачи данных с одной функции в другую

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type='text' onkeyup = "seach('val1', 'val2')">
function seach (id, column) {
        document.onkeyup = function (e) {
            alert (id);
        }
}
```

Вопрос как вывести id на экран в другой функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может Я не понял вопрос, но все работает и без танцев с бубном и допольнительно подвешивания глобального евента `document.onkeyup`

```js
function seach(id, column) {
  alert(' val1 = ' + id + ' val2 = ' + column);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup="seach('val1', 'val2');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто обдумывал вопрос, но ответ нашелся сам собою.

Отвечу на него, да бы облегчить кому то жизнь))

```
<input type='text' onkeyup = "seach('val1', 'val2')">
function seach (id, column) {
        var n_id = id; var n_column = column;
        document.onkeyup = function (e) {
            alert (n_id);
        }
}
```

Comment: Оригинальный код из вопроса тоже должен работать.

Comment: У меня он работал, но не выводил переменные с первой функции.
Для этого нужно было сделать переменные абсолютными

Comment: не знаю почему не работало, может что-то еще поменяли. Вроде бы две приведенные функции (в вопросе и в ответе) полностью эквивалентны. Я не могу придумать условий, при которых они будут работать по-разному.